# Why would an airport be depicted with symbology for runways longer than 8,069 feet even though it is reported on the sectional as 7,200 feet?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts, symbology

This airport, KMKO, Muskogee-Davis Regional in Oklahoma southeast of Tulsa is depicted on the sectional chart with symbology normally reserved for airport with a hard surfaced runway longer than 8069 feet, but this one is only reported on the sectional as 7200.

Is this a mistake by the FAA or is there some clear explanation about why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The FAA [chart user's guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#vfr-terms-airports) says:

> [image] Hard-surfaced runways greater than 8069' or some multiple runways less than 8069'

It's the latter case of some multiple runways less than 8069'.

---

This is also confirmed in the post, "[What is significant about the number 8069 ft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33905/14897)"

> Specialists also place these polygons around the runway pattern of aerodromes with **multiple runways that are less than 8069 feet,** in cases where the multiple runway pattern does not fit into the largest, circular aerodrome symbol.

([FAA FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/faq/#q3b); emphasis mine.)

Most likely MKO doesn't fit in the standard circle [image] because of 36-18 and/or 4-22 intersecting the circumference.

[image]
(Chart Supplement via [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/airport/MKO/Muskogee-Davis-Regional-Airport))